# Taking screenshots of different mobile devices using MVC C#

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC website, which takes a URL from a user and creates screenshots of a complete page. Now we have to use the same for Mobile devices (Android and iOS). Can anybody please suggest a code to take the same. 
Thanks in advance.